# ending haml comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, haml

I am new to haml and this is stumping me. I don't like to delete code where I can comment it out but I have no idea how to properly end a comment in haml.

Here is a code snippit:

```
.field
 = f.label :member_id
 %br/
 = f.text_field :member_id
.field
 = f.label :instrument_type
 %br/
```

I'm trying to comment out the first field so I used:

```
/
.field
 = f.label :member_id
 %br/
 = f.text_field :member_id
.field
 = f.label :instrument_type
 %br/
```

but that commented out everything after the first field.

Then I tried:

```
/
 .field
  = f.label :member_id
  %br/
  = f.text_field :member_id
.field
 = f.label :instrument_type
 %br/
```

but it didn't like that either, or:

```
 -#.field
 -# = f.label :member_id
 -# %br/
 -# = f.text_field :member_id
.field
 = f.label :instrument_type
 %br/
```

I must be missing something. I looked all over but the examples never show code after the comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's your spacing that is causing the problem, not your method. Here is the proper way to comment out those lines in HAML:

**Your 4th example is really close**:

```
 -#.field
 -# = f.label :member_id
 -# %br/
 -# = f.text_field :member_id
.field
 = f.label :instrument_type
 %br/
```

**Commented out properly**:

```
-#.field
-#  = f.label :member_id
-#  %br
-#  = f.text_field :member_id
.field
  = f.label :instrument_type
  %br
```

This is **awfully** close to what you posted on your last example, with a notable exception: Your comment lines begin with a space preceding the `-#`. That space at the beginning **will** break HAML. I also noticed that your source code is indenting by one space instead of two. This will also break HAML. **It must be two spaces of indentation.**

P.S. You can remove the trailing slash from your `%br` lines.

Answer (score 4):

A `/` on a blank line, followed by code, comments an indented section of code which is probably why your entire section of code is getting commented out.

Try commenting each line.

```
/.field<br>
/ = f.label :member_id<br>
/ %br/<br>
/ = f.text_field :member_id<br>
.field<br>
 = f.label :instrument_type<br>
 %br/<br>
```

Or, alternatively a blank line between the fields may give the comment a hint as to where it should end.

```
/    
.field<br>
 = f.label :member_id<br>
 %br/<br>
 = f.text_field :member_id<br>

.field<br>
 = f.label :instrument_type<br>
 %br/<br>
```