# How to comment out a line in HAMLC comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, comments, haml, hamlc

Wondering how to comment out one line in HAMLC. 
I Tried

```
# this is commented out
```

But it doesn't work. It creates a `<div> this is commented out </div>`
Can't find many resources on HAMLC.

Knowing how to comment out multi-line would also be appreciated.

Comment: @antonie did you try: %p code-line-1
-# This is a comment
%p code-line-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the [Haml documentation for comments](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#comments):

Comments

Haml supports two sorts of comments: those that show up in the HTML output and those that don’t.

HTML Comments: /

The forward slash character, when placed at the beginning of a line, wraps all text after it in an HTML comment. For example:

```
%peanutbutterjelly
  / This is the peanutbutterjelly element
  I like sandwiches!
```

is compiled to:

```
<peanutbutterjelly>
  <!-- This is the peanutbutterjelly element -->
  I like sandwiches!
</peanutbutterjelly>
```

The forward slash can also wrap indented sections of code. For example:

```
/
  %p This doesn't render...
  %div
    %h1 Because it's commented out!
```

is compiled to:

```
<!--
  <p>This doesn't render...</p>
  <div>
    <h1>Because it's commented out!</h1>
  </div>
-->
```

Conditional Comments: /[]

You can also use Internet Explorer conditional comments by enclosing the condition in square brackets after the /. For example:

```
/[if IE]
  %a{ :href => 'http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/' }
    %h1 Get Firefox
```

is compiled to:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <a href='http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/'>
    <h1>Get Firefox</h1>
  </a>
<![endif]-->
```

Haml Comments: -#

The hyphen followed immediately by the pound sign signifies a silent comment. Any text following this isn’t rendered in the resulting document at all.

For example:

```
%p foo
-# This is a comment
%p bar
```

is compiled to:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
```

You can also nest text beneath a silent comment. None of this text will be rendered. For example:

```
%p foo
-#
  This won't be displayed
    Nor will this
                   Nor will this.
%p bar
```

is compiled to:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
```

These are other references:

- http://makandracards.com/makandra/689-know-your-haml-comments
- [ending haml comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310761/ending-haml-comments)

Comment: It's very important to clearly credit the source of content. I'd strongly recommend clearly stating where this came from, preferably at the top of the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will add the answer came from. Thanks @theTinMan.

Answer (score 1):

you can comment the line like

For haml tag

`//%div`

and for rails tag

`=# link_to "", ""`

Here is a [comment code of haml](http://makandracards.com/makandra/689-know-your-haml-comments)